# visualizing longitudinal patient data: Adding specific icons or symbols to certain cells in a time series heatmap to indicate events/outcomes

Tags: data-visualization, seaborn, heatmap

I am currently involved in a clinical study. We are trying to visualize patients blood work over time using seaborn cluster maps (for example patient CPR levels). For reference: We have some 200 Patients and up to 60 days of observed data, so cells in the plot are pretty small.

[image: example heatmap]

Some patients during the observations period either died or developed an outcome of interest. We would love to visualize these key events with some form a symbol or icon. I am imagining something like this: 
In addition to its color coding the field at the date of death gehts big dot right in the middle, or even a symbolic cross or some other symbol.

Things that might work, but i do not know how to do:
I am using lines to seperate cells. Changing the widths and color of the cells at the date an event occured might work.

Things that dont work:
cell in my heatmap are too small for custom annotations

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df= pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
heatmap = sns.clustermap(df,col_cluster=False, row_cluster=False, cmap='YlOrRd', mask=df=0, vmax=10, vmin=0, linewidths=1, linecolor='black', figsize=(20,16), cbar_pos=(0.1, 0.2, .02, .6))
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? Could you provide some toy data similar to your real data? Do you have a sample image of a plot? You might be interested in reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)